# Enum features with binary ordinality getting dropped from H2o models

Tags: enums, h2o, xgboost

I have a dataset with 20 enum features (each of which takes 2 distinct string values), one int feature for a binary classification problem. H2o Xgboost is dropping all 20 columns with the warning

> Warning message:
>   In .h2o.startModelJob(algo, params, h2oRestApiVersion) :
>     Dropping bad and constant columns

I have tried setting all columns as strings and also as a factor (enum) but H2o drops all the columns every time. Any suggestions?

Comment: Definitely don’t have your features as the string datatype.  Make them enums.  Use as.factor if needed.  You can also try H2O GBM  to see if only xgboost is behaving unexpectedly.

Comment: Yes. H2O GBM also drops the columns.

Comment: I was using H2O in R when I got this error. Do not get this error in Python. How can I give H2O this feedback?

Comment: Putting enough info to reproduce the problem in this stackoverflow post is one way.